# Como pegar o valor de registro de acordo com o número da posição dele no SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, query

Estou povoando aleatoriamente as tabelas de um banco de dados que criei e estou tentando povoar uma tabela que tem chaves estrangeiras. Minha ideia é criar um while loop e pegar o ID (os valores são aleatórios) da linha @i + 1 e assim povoar a outra tabela com os valores iguais ao ID dessa tabela e assim a ligação funcionar. Tentei algo como:

```
    declare @i bigint
    declare @fkid bigint
    set @i = 1
    while @i < 1000
    begin

    select @fkid = ID from TABELA
    WHERE Row_Number() = @i

    insert into tabela2 (id, fk_wds, nome) values (@i, @fkid, @nome)

set @i += 1
    end
```

Não está dando certo e não faço ideia como fazer, alguém pode ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

A função `Row_Number()` é uma `window function`, você não pode usa-la diretamente no `where` do seu `select`.

O que da pra fazer é algo assim:

```
SELECT @fkid = r_id
  FROM (SELECT Row_Number() over(ORDER BY id) r_id
          FROM TABELA) tab
 WHERE tab.r_id = @i
```

O exemplo completo você pode encontrar [aqui](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6ece4/4/0).

Primeiro você calcula o `Row_Number` em uma query e filtra ela como sendo uma sub-query.